# Authentication of updates and downloads

Tags: authentication

I'm a silver surfer beginner giving Ubuntu a go on my backup PC because my Windows 10 drive has packed in.
Everything is fine until I try to update from v 14 to v 15 or other installed software. These download OK but when I click 'install' I'm asked to authenticate with a password. I enter my administrator password and click authenticate, this fails and loops back to request a password. Frustrated to say the least.
Regards WilRog.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the sudo mechanism, rather than an administrator account. This allows the main user (and others, if configured) to elevate their privileges to run a command.

Enter your password at these prompts, not the admin password.

Comment: I note your comment. I set a user password and entered that but still got  the same result.

Answer (score 0):

That most likely means you mistyped the password.

The password it asks for IS an administrator (aka "sudo") password but the password it asks is the one you provided during installation of the system and what is set for your *main* account. Type it out in gEdit so you can see you type it correctly (like capitals/small characters) and try with a copy/paste.

A last option would be to reset it: you can do it with a live session (see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) ).

Comment: After Darien Freeheart's advice I double checked spelling but still got same error. I have used both passwords so far.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. It was so simple and may help others with similar.
I downloaded the Ubuntu 15.04 ISO Image (1.2GB), I had v 14 installed. I burned the image to a 4.7GB DVD Disc, CDs are only 650MBs, everything including Disc verification went faultlessly. 
With the Disc inserted I rebooted the PC. At start-up you have the option to trial v 15.04 or install. after 10-15 minutes checking that all my files functioned OK I installed the update. Password authentication works perfectly plus I have updated software all in one go. I chose to install v15.04 alongside v14 just in case, this will be deleted later. 
Thanks to all who replied to my plea for help. I still can not believe the answer was so simple.
Regards Wilrog.